# Why do I keep getting 'ImportError: cannot import name db'?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am following this tutorial: [getting started with flask-login](https://medium.com/@perwagnernielsen/getting-started-with-flask-login-can-be-a-bit-daunting-in-this-tutorial-i-will-use-d68791e9b5b5).

However I am stuck at step 5 where I start to use SQLAlchemy. I believe the problem might be circular importing, based on what I have read but I'm still a little new to Python coding. This web app is a little project I am doing in my free time.

So I guess my overall question is, is this circular importing, and if not does anyone see what I might be doing wrong here? I am also running this using virtualenv using Python 2.7.

File Structure:

```
-noteapp
  -noteapp
    -db
    -forms
    -static
    -templates
    -views
  __init__.py 
  app.py
  models.py
```

This is my app.py file

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from noteapp.models import db

from noteapp.views.index import bp as index_bp
from noteapp.views.createnote import bp as createnote_bp
from noteapp.views.signup import bp as signup_bp

def init_db():
    db.init_app(app)
    db.app = app
    db.create_all()

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = 'removed for reasons'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'removed for reasons'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.init_app(app)

app.register_blueprint(index_bp)
app.register_blueprint(createnote_bp)
app.register_blueprint(signup_bp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.init_db()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my models.py file:

```
from noteapp.app import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.email
```

Comment: It does look like a circular dependency. In `app.py` you import from `models.py` and in `models.py` you import `app` from `app.py`.

Comment: On top: `from noteapp.models import db` somewhere down below `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` ... do you think it is a good idea to shadow your imported thing with a lokal variable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct you have a circle import issue.

At `app.py` you import `from noteapp.models import db`,
and at `models.py` you import `from noteapp.app import app`

A quick fix could be:
at `models.py` use `db = SQLAlchemy()` without the `app`.
At the `app.py` module, import db from models.py and do `db.init_app(app)`

also remove `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` from your app.py

your app.py should look like this..

```
from noteapp.models import db
...
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'removed for reasons'
...
def init_db():
    db.init_app(app)
    db.app = app
    db.create_all()
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.init_db()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

models.py should look like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    email = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))
    def __init__(self, email, password):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.email
```

Comment: WOW, thank you so much. It's working great now and I managed to get it working with my MySQL database as well.

Comment: `app.init_db()` gave me an error, `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'init_db'` however `init_db()` worked. is this supposed to work this way ?